# 4pin CPU connectors on HP Omen 45L

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, computer-building

I'm replacing PSU in my Omen HP 45L and having an issue figuring out what the two 4pin power connectors are on the motherboard.

The new PSU is modular (MSI MPG A1000G) and doesn't come with 4pin cable in the box, although it does have 8pin. I figured I need to connect my 8pin one into 2 x 4pin ones on the motherboard so I got this cable [https://www.amazon.com/COMeap-Detachable-EPS-12V-Motherboard-Adapter/dp/B07VF887KN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VF887KN)

The motherboard used in Omen HP 45L is BlizzardOC https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/ish_5037050-5037113-16 but I don't see anything in the spec about these connectors.

The problem is that the split cable I got from Amazon only fits one of the 4 pin connectors. The other one doesn't go in because the side that has a locking hitch doesn't match with what's on the motherboard. In other words, 4 pin connectors on the old PSU and the 4 pin connectors on the new split cable don't match when it comes to their pattern (round vs. square) and where the locking hitch is.

I'm completely bewildered here — is this a proprietary motherboard or are 4 pin CPU connectors common? Why can't I just plug them in? Is it common for locking hitch to not align sometimes? Is there anything else I can do here?

Would appreciate any clues!

[image: pins]

[image: motherboard]

Comment: One of the 4-pin connectors on the motherboard is rotated 90 degrees from the other, but apart from that they look identically keyed. Your splitter looks identical too.

Comment: It is an HP. Lots of proprietary parts are to be expected. And HP is notorious for non-standard power-supplies. Unless you can work out the pin-out of the motherboard connectors (which pin(s) carry 12V and which ones carry 0V/GND) I wouldn't plug in anything. If you get it wrong you may fry the motherboard.